# How do I append a custom error message to Django Rest Framework validation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple viewset,

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    # more properties below.

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serialized_data = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            # method to create a user.
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            print serialized_data.errors,
            print serialized_data.error_messages

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

which uses the following serializer,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    error_messages = {}

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "email", 'password', "username")
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def validate_email(self, value):
        required_value = "" #something that doesn't matter here
        if value is not required_vaue:
            # i want to append the custom error message to the serializer
            error_messages = {"email": {"invalid": "the email is not acceptable!"}} 

        return value
```

I'm trying to inject/append the custom error message to the error register of the serializer with the custom `validate_email` method, so that I can use it with `serialized_data.error_messages`.

Answer (score 1):

You should raise validation error:

```
raise serializers.ValidationError("the email is not acceptable!")
```

Or try writing custom validators http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators

It is not in the official documentation, but you can try appending error message to `self.errors[field_name]`

Comment: can I append the errors to `serialized_data.error_messages`??